# Removing contenteditable attribute on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an interface, which allows a user to edit a div by right clicking on the div. I have been able to achieve this using jquery.

After the user is done editing, and the mouse moves out of the div, I want the div to become non-editable as before. I figured out that I can use mouseleave function of jquery, but I am not sure where exactly this should be written. I tried using the mouseevent as shown below, but it does not work.

```
$(".list").contextMenu({
        menu: 'listMenu'
    },
    function(action, el, pos) {
        if(action=='edit'){
            $(el).attr('contenteditable','true');
            $(e1).mouseleave(function() {
                $(e1).attr('contenteditable','false');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What is e1? Possible el? (small L on end)

Comment: Change "e1" to "el" and then tell us what is the problem.

Comment: The typo ExpertSystem and maximkou already mentioned is the problem :). You've mispelled `el` (a lower case `EL`) as `e1` (a lower case E and a one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instad:

```
$( el ).prop('contenteditable', false );
```

&&

```
$( el ).prop('contenteditable', true );
```

- note that I'm using Boolen values, not string.

And as mentioned in comments you have a typo: `e1` should be `el`